# using "did" twice in a sentence

Tags: grammar

i was watching a show yesterday and one of the lines was "So did anything we did matter?" or something of the sort.

as far as i remember from school(it has been a few years) you cant use "did" twice in the same sentence. so is the sentence above correct? i know stuff on tv isn't always grammatically correct but maybe there is a rule that i'm not aware of. if so someone please explain.

Comment: There is no such rule, and there's nothing (grammatically) wrong with that sentence.

Comment: It wouldn't look very good to repeat a word like that in formal written work, but it's fine in everyday conversation.

Comment: It's fine, but just sounds a bit off like '*do do*' - "People don't do work on the weekend. Actually, some people **do** *do work* on the weekend"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the phrase was

> So, did anything we did matter?

*anything we did* is the subject of the phrase. Therefore, one *did* has no connection to the other.

Try to substitute *anything we did* with *it* or *this*, and the phrase will be

> So, did **it** matter?

which I'm hoping makes sense to you.